# Bootstrap left brand list strange positioning when navigation collapses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my website to have 2 buttons next to the `navbar-brand` that will remain there no matter what size the screen is. I have the collapsible elements from the right setup to collapse when the screen is mobile sized. The issue I'm having is that when the nav collapses the positioning of the list is messed up. I've tried changing margins, widths, and padding for the ul on the right but it does not seem to fix the issue.

I intend for the navbar to look like this when the collapse is active, not only while it's open.[image]

This is what happens once the navbar collapses, I've inspected the elements and it seems that the left buttons have a width that is 100% but upon changing that I get stuck with a margin that I cannot change. 
[image]

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQBqyX)

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to be like this:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYvabM?editors=1000#0

Comment: That's close but I only want the buttons on the left, the wrench and the question to be inline and in the same position with all screen sizes. The collapse menu is working just as intended.

Comment: I hope this is what you are looking for http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGLZME?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/9crjjnpz/)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav icons">
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I moved the `ul` with `icons` after the `navbar-brand`